# Meanings of root system: Show definitions/intuitions and $Λ_{root} ⊂ Λ_{char} ⊂ Λ_{weight}?$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let G be a compact Lie group. Let $g_{\mathbb{C}}$ be the associated complex Lie
algebra. There is a root system associated to $g_{\mathbb{C}}$. Denote this by a
4-tuple $$R = \{Λ_{root}, Λ_{weight}, Λ_{co−root}, Λ_{co−weight}\}.$$

$T$ is a maximal torus of G,

$Λ_{char }= Hom(T,U(1))$.

$Λ_{cochar }= Hom(U(1),T)$.

Can you help on showing/explaining:

1. Definitions and intuitions of $Λ_{root}, Λ_{char}, Λ_{weight}$?
2. Definitions and intuitions of $Λ_{coroot}, Λ_{cochar}, Λ_{coweight}$?
3. How to show in general, $$Λ_{root} ⊂ Λ_{char} ⊂ Λ_{weight}?$$
4. How to show in general, $$Λ_{coroot} ⊂ Λ_{cochar} ⊂ Λ_{coweight}?$$
5. When would some of $Λ_{root}, Λ_{char}, Λ_{weight}$ and some of $Λ_{coroot}, Λ_{cochar}, Λ_{coweight}$ overlap to be the same?

Comment: What is the source of this definition?

Comment: Start your studies from the beginning. If you don't know the meanings of these concepts, back up to the point where they are defined. We don't know what you are studying from, what your prior knowledge is, or what you are trying to accomplish, so the best advice I can give is, you need to either go back in your book to a previous chapter, or consult the references of whatever you are trying to study.